# Why does Poland receive more in gross and (far more in) net EU funding than any other member state?

Tags: european-union, budget, poland, public-funding

Poland receives more gross and significantly more net EU funding than any other member state, including significantly more than other Eastern members (e.g. Romania or Bulgaria).  The stark disparity is seen in this chart, taken from [this  UK House of Commons report](http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-7847/CBP-7847.pdf) (PDF, 1.86 MB):
[image]

Why does Poland receive so much EU funding (particularly net EU funding) compared to other countries?

Comment: Detailed information https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pByvxVesA2jLFbaoXwjkfH1Tz2bmKgdEAcOL6n1Cods/edit#gid=12

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## A combination of:

### 1. Low per capita income

While not among the very poorest countries in the EU, Poland is far from being the richest. [Per capita income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_Europe_by_GNI_(nominal)_per_capita) in Poland is $12680, compared with $43660 in Germany and $9470 in Romania. This means Poland's per capita contribution to the EU budget is comparatively low.

### 2. Large population

Poland is much larger than other low-income EU countries. It has a [population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_population) of 38.5 million, compared with 19.8 million in Romania.

Items (1) and (2) together increase Poland's eligibility for investment from the EU's [Structural Funds and Cohesion Fund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_Funds_and_Cohesion_Fund).

### 3. Large agricultural sector

Farms are eligible for funding under the EU Common Agricultural Policy (CAP), and Poland has a lot of farms -- although its agricultural sector has [consolidated](https://ec.europa.eu/agriculture/sites/agriculture/files/policy-perspectives/policy-briefs/enlargement/pl_en.pdf) into fewer and larger farms since it joined the EU.

The CAP explains why France receives much more EU funding than the UK, even though they have similar population and income.